# Append same row to each element of 1 column vector. Fast solution for Matlab needed

Tags: matlab, performance

I have column vector `V=randi(10,1,10^7)'` and I have row vector `R=randi(10,1,10^2)`.

I need a fast solution to create matrix `M`, where to the end of `R` i will append values from `V`.

I use simple `repmat` approach:

```
M=[repmat(R,numel(V),1),V]
```

**Is it possible to speedup this operation?**

Comment: I don't think you can optimise this further out of the box. You are already using highly optimised built-in functions. Note that `M` will be `~8GB`! Avoiding the need to calculate `M` is probably the way to go. Why do you need this matrix?

Comment: Memory is not a problem (I have 256 GB). M is an input to some third-party function, which I could not change.

Comment: Even if you have 256GB (of RAM) it will take time to fill it.

Comment: YES! :) It is server...

Comment: How long does this operation take on your machine?

Comment: Elapsed time is 4.403646 seconds.

Comment: Is your actual data integers or is that just for the sake of an example?

Comment: just for example

Comment: If they're floats then the answer you just accepted is going to destroy your data...

Comment: no their are all integers!!! That's why I accept answer it really helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
Use 'int8' or 'uint8', it will take 1/8 memory, and almost x8 faster to build.

```
V=randi(10,10^7,1,'int8');
R=randi(10,1,10^2,'int8');
tic;
M=[repmat(R,numel(V),1),V];
toc
```

Comment: Note that `int8` and `uint8` have [maximum values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html) of `127` and `255`, respectively. It should be emphasized that the user select the appropriate integer class for their data to avoid destroying it.